# Swap Images on Mouse roll over [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="imageBox">
    <img id="cat1" onmouseover="swapImage1()" src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="Cat Picture 1" height="272" width="272">
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function swapImage1() {
    document.getElementByID('cat1').src = "images/cat2.jpg";
}
```

How come whenever I roll my cursor over `cat1.jpg` it doesn't change into `cat2.jpg`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, `...getElementById(...)`. BTW, if you pass *this* from the listener, you don't need *getElementById* at all.

Comment: `getElementByID` ==> `getElementById`